# Problem on $f(x) =(-x^3 +15)/7,$ number of sol. of $f(x) =f^{-1}(x) =?$

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions, inverse-function

Let $f(x) = (- x^3 + 15)/7$, let $\alpha$ be the number of real roots of $f(x) = f^{-1} (x)$, and let $\beta$ be the number of real roots of $f(x) = x$. What is $|\alpha - \beta|?$

On a quick glance and drawing the graph, the answer seems to be $2$ ($\alpha=3$, $\beta=1$), but the actual answer is $5$ ($\alpha=5$, $\beta=1$). I am unable to find a way to find $\alpha$; please give a detailed solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ is equivalent to $f(f(x))=x.$

Comment: since f(x) is of degree 3, it can't have 5 roots. Also, f(x) is used with 2 definitions in the same question.

Comment: Sometimes, drawing a better graph helps: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zozlpzsr0c

Comment: @NoChance from Thomas' comment it isn't $f(x)$ but $f(f(x))-x$ whose roots re sought.

Comment: @coffeemath. thanks for the clarification. I will try to put an answer.

Comment: @NoChance The Desmos linked by Mark H in his comment looks like 4 solutions, with two of the crossings appearing close to a single tangency. It would be good if someone looked at the actual polynomial equation to prove what the number of solutions is.

Comment: @coffeemath, Good idea. I have added a link as per your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I assumed that finding the roots is not what the OP is after, so I did not detail how can the root values be obtained. I focused on finding the value of $|\alpha - \beta|$. I used [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mvvfsexu5f) to find the roots.

$$f(x)= \frac{1}{7}\left(-x^{3}+15\right)$$

Since (see notes above by Thomas Andrews and Coffeemath): $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ Is equivalent to:

$$ f(f(x))=x$$

And since $\alpha$ is the number of roots for: $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$, $\alpha$ is the number of roots for:

$$f(f(x))-x=0$$

Which can be written as:
$$g_{1}(x)=\left(-\frac{\left(\left(-\frac{x^{3}}{7}+\frac{15}{7}\right)\right)^{3}}{7}+\frac{15}{7}\right)-x=0$$

The above has the real roots: $x=-1.84, x=1,x= 1.58, x=2$ and $x=3.032$ (note that the above is a polynomial of degree $9$). We can conclude that:
$$\alpha = 5$$

It is also given that the number of roots for $f(x)-x$ is $\beta$. The expression can be written as:

$$g_{2}(x)=\frac{1}{7}\left(-x^{3}+15\right)-x$$

The above polynomial has 1 real root of value:$1.58$, so:
$$\beta = 1$$

$$ |\alpha - \beta| = |5-1| = 4$$